# Where are the svn binaries located in Windows after installing tortoisesvn?

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I have someone who installed tortoisesvn on their computer, and now we're trying to find where the svn binaries are located so we can use a different set of binaries, but we're not sure where they're located.

Any information would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Process Explorer from SysInternals.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653
Find the process when you're running it, and it'll show you where it resides.  And what DLLs it loads, where they are, etc..
I realize that this is a very generic answer, that's intentional!

Comment: @manojlds - give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach him to fish, feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: @Chris, you deserve more rep.

Comment: If you don't have access to install and/or run process explorer then this answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN does not include (normally) svn command line tools. The 1.7 beta version *does* because there are limited places to get the binaries at this time.

Just install whatever command line tools you want, and make sure they are in the path (and before TortoiseSVN for 1.7).

Comment: Do you know where the SVN binaries might be right now? We have both smartsvn and tortoisesvn working, so I know the binaries exist at the moment.

Comment: Where was it installed to? I would look there first.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is because I have no idea where it was installed. I certainly would have looked there first.

Comment: If they work from the command line, it must be in the path. So take a look at the PATH environment variable. You could also do a find on svn.exe as well.